# Cassandra does not start on Java 10

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have a brand new Windows 10 Home installation, with a brand-new installation of JDK 10.0.1 (which is what Oracle recommended when I went to the JDK download site.) I just now downloaded Cassandra 3.11.2, un-tar'd it, and put the bin directory on my classpath.

When I attempt to start Cassandra using the `cassandra -f` command, I get this error:

```
PS C:\javatools> cassandra -f
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
WARNING! Automatic page file configuration detected.
 It is recommended that you disable swap when running Cassandra
 for performance and stability reasons.
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
Failed 64-bit check. Re-running to get version from 32-bit
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
Cassandra 3.0 and later require Java 8u40 or later.
```

Java 10 is clearly "Java 8 rel 40 or later". I verified that I was, in fact, running the version of Java I thought I was:

```
PS C:\javatools> java -version
java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)
```

How can I get Cassandra to recognize that I do, in fact, have "Java 8u40 or later"?

Comment: There is a bit of discourse in the dev community right now, about how to handle Java's new 6 month release schedule.  But stick with Java 8, and you cannot go wrong.

Comment: It baffles me how agile devs, such as myself, insist on providing their users with super short release cycles (eg 2 weeks), and then get all bent out of shape when out own vendors proceed to do something similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cassandra does not support any Java release newer than Java 8.

References are as follows:

- declined bug report against Java 9: [CASSANDRA-9608](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9608)
- declined bug report against Java 10: [CASSANDRA-14446](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14446)

Furthermore, even though the documentation does indicate it's a "work in progress", it does indicate the following on the [Getting Started](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/getting_started/installing.html#installation-from-binary-tarball-files) page:

> Prerequisites
>
> The latest version of Java 8, either the Oracle Java Standard Edition
>   8 or OpenJDK 8. To verify that you have the correct version of java
>   installed, type java -version.

While it doesn't explicitly say "Java 9 and newer are not supported", this is apparently supposed to be inferred from this indicator.

Finally, the misleading error message appears to be a wontfix item.

Comment: slight correction:  CASSANDRA-9608 is not declined, it's in a 'READY TO COMMIT' state

Comment: Well given that Java 9 is end of life and no longer even downloadable, I'm not entirely sure how helpful this is. Plus the 14446 ticket does refer back to 9608 as "proof" so...

Comment: I believe the plan is to support java 11 on cassandra 4.0

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to run cassandra 3.11.3 on java-11-openjdk-amd64 on localhost (ubuntu 18.04).
(Strangely, java -version shows `openjdk version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17`)

I tweaked a lot in jvm.options, because many gc options are not supported anymore, and ThreadPriorityPolicy could not be set to 42. (last thing is most annoying: it was really good compaction threads were low priority).

Also, to run `nodetool` I have to specify jvm 1.8 by `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: The fact that you've managed to run it doesn't help the others. You should be more accurate at what options and params did you use!

Comment: I didn't save config file, but It is not hard to repeat my investigation. Just 10-15 minutes and voilà you have working cassandra.

Comment: 1. I doubt you have "working cassandra" by just tweaking the jvm options. You may have managed to start it, but working properly without issues on java 11 is a different story. 2. "tweaked a lot in jvm.options" contradicts with 10-15 min and voila...

Comment: 1. Well, I did it on my working computer, and it was not production one. But I was able to interract with cassandra (stress test on insertion data and query them) without any issue. There is one known regression bound to ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 : cassandra will not be able to set compaction thread as low priority. But if you have one-two cpu core free in steady state, then it is not an issue.

Comment: 2. Most annoying thing were founding the way how to run cassandra in command line without init script. `sudo -u cassandra cassandra`. After that every tume you try to run you see next jvm option you need to comment. 10-15 minutes, and voila.