# Does Cassandra support Java 10?

Tags: cassandra, java-10

We're planning on migrating our environment from Java 8 to OpenJDK 10. Doing this on my local machine, I've found that Cassandra will no longer start for me, giving the following error :

[image]

I can't find any solid information online that says it is definitely not supported.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50362215/cassandra-does-not-start-on-java-10) from 4 months ago suggests that they do not support Java 10, but doesn't say it is confirmed, and is more inferred. There is also a comment on it from another user saying they have managed to get it running on Java 11.

The final comment on [this ticket](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-1795) on datastax says "We've updated our CI matrix to include Java 10 and everything works except for the aforementioned OSGi testing issues." I'm not sure what to take away from that, but it seems to imply that it is working with Java 10 now, as the ticket is marked as resolved.

[This ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9608), they discuss support for Java 11. There are a few comments discussing the need to even support Java 10, but they don't really give a definitive answer on whether they will or not.

Finally [this blog](http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2018/08/16/java11.html) discusses a way to get Java 11 working with cassandra. However I notice this is using Cassandra 4.0. Has this officially been released? I notice on their [website](http://cassandra.apache.org/download/) they say the release date is tbd and says the current stable release is 3.11.3, and there is no mention of it on their [compatibility page](https://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/compatibility.html).

I currently installed Cassandra on windows via Datastax, but I have also tried cloning the current git repository and running it from there, but I get the same error message (although on their github they do seem to say it has only been tested with Java 8).

Do they simply not support 10 then? Also if anyone knows if they plan to release 4.0 soon, and if that will definitely support 11 (and I assume 10 ?), that would be a massive help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Cassandra 4.0 has explicit support for both Java 8 and Java 11.  In fact, they even split-up the configuration files as such:

```
$ pwd
/Users/aaron/local/apache-cassandra-4.0-SNAPSHOT/conf
$ ls -a jvm*
jvm-clients.options jvm11-clients.options   jvm8-clients.options
jvm-server.options  jvm11-server.options    jvm8-server.options
```

The reason for support of these specific versions is two-fold.  First of all, Java 8 has been the de-facto standard for Cassandra for a few years now.  Users expect that it will still work on Java 8 in the future.

Given the new 6 month release cycle of Java, Java 9 and Java 10 will no longer be "current" when Apache Cassandra 4.0 comes out.  Plus, the tests which run during the build have shown to be picky about which version of Java they work with.  Therefore, the decision was made to go support Java 8 and 11 for 4.0, as work on Java 9 and 10 seemed to be lower-priority.

That's not to say that Cassandra 4.0 won't *run* on Java 9 or 10.  In fact, [CASSANDRA-9608](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9608) even has a patch submitted which *should* cover it.  But the fact remains that Java 8 is included due to its longstanding use in the Cassandra user base.  Java 11 will be the current JDK/JRE at the time 4.0 releases.  If you want to be sure that your cluster will run well, I'd pick one of those two.

But until 4.0, the most recent patch of Java 8 is really the only option.

Comment: Ok that's fine, thanks for the response! Do you know when they plan to release 4.0?

Comment: @user3275784 There is currently a code freeze on the 4.0 branch and the community is currently focusing on QA. There is no release date set afaik as the focus on quality rather then fast release. A very rough guess from me would be Q2 2019 but it's hard to tell right now. If you're interested in updates you should follow the user lists: https://cassandra.apache.org/community/

Answer (score 8):

With Cassandra 3.11.4 we have been able to execute the Cassandra engine with Java 11, but there has been some gotchas:

- If for any reason you are still using CMS for garbage collection, it would be the time to move to G1; this is set up in the `jvm.options` file.
- Also in jvm.options, you will need to disable the `ThreadPriorityPolicy` as it was deprecated with [Java 9](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-13107)
- With the unified logging of gc activity, introduced with Java 9, you will need to remove gc specific parameters in `jvm.options`. Some of those parameters are:

  - -Xloggc
  - -XX:+PrintGCDetails
  - -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
  - -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC
  - -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
  - -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
  - -XX:+PrintPromotionFailure
- `nodetool` still requires Java 8 to be able to execute.

  - We have both JVM installed, and used alternatives to set Java 11 as the default. This is also the value of the JAVA_HOME variable
  - We have a new variable called JAVA8_HOME that points to that version
  - We updated the nodetool script (in our case it was in /usr/bin/nodetool) to use JAVA8_HOME when setting the JAVA variable
- For a cluster that was using `offheap_buffers` for `memtable_allocation_type` (it is defined in `cassandra.yaml`), we had to change it to use `offheap_objects`

Comment: In addition, I commented out all log-related options like -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation!

Answer (score 6):

Released versions of Cassandra support only Java 8 - support for higher versions will be in the Cassandra 4.0 that isn't released yet.  You can track progress in the [CASSANDRA-9608](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9608)

Answer (score 1):

As of now, Cassandra 3.x will only work with java 8. Cassandra 4.0 supports Java 8 and Java 11 but it is not released yet at the time of writing this answer.

If you want to run Cassandra in your local system(not recommended for production) with java 11. Then you can follow these steps:

> Prerequisite: Java 11, Apache Ant, Python

1. Download Cassandra trunk branch code : https://github.com/apache/cassandra
2. Unzip the file and open folder in terminal/command prompt .
3. Build cassandra with -Duse.jdk11=true argument:

```
ajit-soman@ajitsoman-X542BA:~/Downloads/cassandra-trunk$ ant -Duse.jdk11=true
Buildfile: /home/ajit-soman/Downloads/cassandra-trunk/build.xml
   [script] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
...
...
jar:
[mkdir] Created dir: /home/ajit-soman/Downloads/cassandra-trunk/build/classes/stress/META-INF
[mkdir] Created dir: /home/ajit-soman/Downloads/cassandra-trunk/build/tools/lib
  [jar] Building jar: /home/ajit-soman/Downloads/cassandra-trunk/build/tools/lib/stress.jar
[mkdir] Created dir: /home/ajit-soman/Downloads/cassandra-trunk/build/classes/fqltool/META-INF
  [jar] Building jar: /home/ajit-soman/Downloads/cassandra-trunk/build/tools/lib/fqltool.jar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 7 minutes 38 seconds
```

4. Navigate to the bin folder and run Cassandra:

```
ajit-soman@ajitsoman-X542BA:~/Downloads/cassandra-trunk/bin$ ./cassandra 
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
CompileCommand: dontinline
```

5. Check nodetool status

```
ajit-soman@ajitsoman-X542BA:~/Downloads/cassandra-trunk/bin$ ./nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load      Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack 
UN  127.0.0.1  5.79 KiB  256     100.0%            68687cfd-a80b-45db-93cd-7bc2d212a64b  rack1
```

6. Run cqlsh

```
ajit-soman@ajitsoman-X542BA:~/Downloads/cassandra-trunk/bin$ ./cqlsh 
Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 4.0-alpha2-SNAPSHOT | CQL spec 3.4.5 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh>
```