# Embedded cassandra not working after jdk10 upgrade

Tags: cassandra, spring-data-cassandra, embedded-database, embedded-cassandra

Embedded cassandra not working after jdk10 upgrade. Could some one help me on this.

Cassandra config:

```
try {
            EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra(); 
        }catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(" CommonConfig ",
                    " cluster()::Exception while creating cluster ", e);
            System.setProperty("cassandra.config", "cassandra.yaml");
            DatabaseDescriptor.daemonInitialization();
            EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra();
        }
        Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
                .addContactPoints(environment.getProperty(TextToClipConstants.CASSANDRA_CONTACT_POINTS)).withPort(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty(TextToClipConstants.CASSANDRA_PORT))).build();
        Session session = cluster.connect(); 
        session.execute(KEYSPACE_CREATION_QUERY);
        session.execute(KEYSPACE_ACTIVATE_QUERY);
```

build.gradle

```
import com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.image.Dockerfile
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os


buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath ("com.bmuschko:gradle-docker-plugin:3.2.1")
        classpath ("org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.5")
        classpath("au.com.dius:pact-jvm-provider-gradle_2.12:3.5.13")
        classpath ("com.moowork.gradle:gradle-node-plugin:1.2.0")

    }
}

plugins {
    //id "au.com.dius.pact" version "3.5.7"
    id "com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties" version "1.4.17"
    id "de.undercouch.download" version "3.4.2"

}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.docker-remote-api'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
apply plugin: 'au.com.dius.pact'
apply plugin: 'scala'




sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    mavenLocal()
}


ext {
    springCloudVersion = 'Finchley.RELEASE'
}

pact {
    serviceProviders {
        rxorder {
            publish {
                pactDirectory = '/Users/sv/Documents/wag-doc-text2clip/target/pacts' // defaults to $buildDir/pacts
                pactBrokerUrl = 'http://localhost:80'
                version=2.0
            }
        }
    }
}

//start of integration tests changes
sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        java {
            compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
            srcDir file('test/functional-api/java')
        }
        resources.srcDir file('test/functional-api/resources')
    }
}

configurations {
    integrationTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    integrationTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}
//end of integration tests changes
dependencies {
    //web (Tomcat, Logging, Rest)
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot',   name: 'spring-boot-starter-web'
    // Redis
    //compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-redis'
    //Mongo Starter
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name:'spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'

    // Configuration processor - To Generate MetaData Files. The files are designed to let  developers offer â€œcode completionâ€? as users are working with application.properties
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    // Actuator - Monitoring
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator'

    //Sleuth - Tracing
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-sleuth'
    //Hystrix - Circuit Breaker
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix'
    // Hystrix - Dashboard
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix-dashboard'
    // Thymeleaf
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    //Voltage
    // Device Detection

    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra', version:'2.0.4.RELEASE'  
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '23.2-jre'
    compile('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0')
    compile('org.json:json:20170516')

    //Swagger
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version:'2.8.0'
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version:'2.8.0'

    //jkd10 fixes
    compile group: 'javax.xml.bind',name: 'jaxb-api', version:'2.3.0'
    compile group: 'javax.xml.soap', name: 'javax.xml.soap-api', version:'1.3.5'
    compile group: 'com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj', name: 'saaj-impl', version:'1.4.0'
    compile group: 'javax.activation', name: 'activation', version: '1.1.1'
    compile group: 'org.glassfish.jaxb', name: 'jaxb-runtime', version:'2.3.0.1'
    testCompile group: 'net.sourceforge.cobertura', name: 'cobertura', version: '2.1.1'

    //Lombok
    compileOnly group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok'
    compile group: 'io.smartcat', name: 'cassandra-diagnostics-connector21', version: '1.4.10'
    //Testing
    //Spring  WS Test
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.ws', name: 'spring-ws-test', version:'2.4.0.RELEASE'

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'){
        exclude group: "com.vaadin.external.google", module:"android-json"
    }
    //Pact
    testCompile group: 'au.com.dius', name: 'pact-jvm-provider-gradle_2.12', version: '3.5.7'
    testCompile group: 'au.com.dius', name:'pact-jvm-provider-junit_2.12',version:'3.5.13'
    testCompile group: 'au.com.dius', name:'pact-jvm-consumer-junit_2.12', version:'3.5.13'

    //Embedded mongo for testing
    testCompile group: 'de.flapdoodle.embed', name:'de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo',version:'2.0.1'
    //testCompile group: 'cz.jirutka.spring', name: 'embedmongo-spring', version: '1.1'

    compile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-jvm', version: '1.2.5'
    testCompile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-junit', version: '3.0.2'
    compile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-spring', version: '3.0.2'

    testCompile('org.cassandraunit:cassandra-unit-spring:3.5.0.1'){
        exclude group: 'org.cassandraunit', module: 'cassandra-unit'
    }
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.cassandraunit/cassandra-unit-shaded
    compile group: 'org.cassandraunit', name: 'cassandra-unit-shaded', version: '3.5.0.1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hectorclient/hector-core
    compile group: 'org.hectorclient', name: 'hector-core', version: '2.0-0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.cassandra', name: 'cassandra-all', version: '3.11.3'
    integrationTestCompile group: 'org.springframework.ws', name: 'spring-ws-test', version:'2.4.0.RELEASE' //changes for integration tests
    integrationTestCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test"){ //changes for integration tests
        exclude group: "com.vaadin.external.google", module:"android-json"
    }
    //integrationTestCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-junit', version: '1.2.5' //changes for integration tests
    //integrationTestCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-spring', version: '1.2.5' //changes for integration tests

}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }

}

test {
    //ignoreFailures = true
    reports.junitXml.enabled = false
    reports.html.enabled = true
    testLogging {
        exceptionFormat = 'full'
    }
    jacoco {
        append = false
        destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/jacocoTest.exec")
        maxHeapSize = '2048m'
        minHeapSize = '1024m'
        //classDumpDir = file("$buildDir/jacoco/classpathdumps")
    }
}
jacocoTestReport {
    group = "Reporting"
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination "${buildDir}/reports/coverage"
    }
    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories = files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it,
                    exclude: [
                                '**/config*',
                                '**/coupons/TextToClipApplication*',
                                '**/bean/*Request*',
                                '**/bean/*Response*',
                    ])
        })
    }
}
test.finalizedBy jacocoTestReport

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.2"
    reportsDir = file("$buildDir/customJacocoReportDir")
}



task createDockerfile(type: Dockerfile,dependsOn:'unzipVoltageDependencies') {
    println 'createDockerfile'

        println 'createDockerfile'
        //Dockerfile path
        destFile = project.file('Dockerfile')

        //Base Image
        from 'nonprodregistry.azurecr.io/baseimg/zulu-openjdk_10u02_ubuntu18.04:v1'
        //from 'nonprodregistry.azurecr.io/zulu-openjdk:8'

        copyFile 'voltage-dependencies/', '/usr/local/ecomm/voltage-dependencies/'



        //Add Springboot Jar
        addFile '/build/libs/' + project.name + '.jar', '/usr/local/ecomm/app/' + project.name + '.jar'



}

/**
 For Voltage dependencies
*/



springBoot {
    buildInfo {
        properties {
            additional = [
                    'time': buildTime()
            ]
        }
    }
}

def buildTime() {
    final dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ")
    dateFormat.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone('CST')
    dateFormat.format(new Date())
}

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property 'sonar.projectName', 'text2clip'
        property 'sonar.coverage.exclusions', "**/config/*,**/coupons/TextToClipApplication*,**/bean/*,**/collection/*"     
    }
}

//start of changes for integration tests
task apifunctionaltest(type: Test) {
    systemProperty "integrationurl", System.getProperty("integrationurl")
    reports.junitXml.enabled = false
    reports.html.enabled = true
    testLogging {
        exceptionFormat = 'full'
    }
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
    reports.html.destination = file("${reporting.baseDir}/${name}")
}
```

//end of changes for integration tests

Anyone has faced this issue before or during jdk10 upgrade.

I tried with different versions, but no help. It looks like some version conflict, but not able to find it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Probably want to read through: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52334649/does-cassandra-support-java-10

Comment: The short answer, is that "yes" others have faced that issue. "No" there isn't anything that can be done about it.  You'll need to use JDK 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the current Cassandra versions are not compatible with jdk10. You'll have to downgrade your java to jdk8.

Comment: Is it still not compatible with JDK 11?

Comment: yu.pitomets - Cassandra 4 will have JDK11 compatibility according to these docs [https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/new/java11.html]. But C* 3.x still only supports JDK8

Comment: I am trying to run with Azul Zulu Build of OpenJDK 11 and seems like it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/nosan/embedded-cassandra

Java home can be set during initialization.