# What Java version is supported with Cassandra 2.1.13

Tags: java, cassandra

I have one machine running with Cassandra 2.1.13 and Java 8.

Currently am looking into upgrading the Java version to Java 10

Looked into couple of links and Java 10 support whether a compatible version is not evident.

References:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14446
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9608

[Cassandra does not start on Java 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50362215/cassandra-does-not-start-on-java-10)

Is there any documentation where the compatible Java version is explicitly mentioned?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra 2 supports Java 8.

Cassandra 3 supports Java 8.

Cassandra 4 (not released yet) will support both Java 8 and later.

So, to answer your question, don't upgrade to Java 10. Stay on Java 8.

This is related - [Does Cassandra support Java 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52334649/does-cassandra-support-java-10/)

Comment: Thanks for the details, they are helpful !

Comment: I hope that my answer will help you to get the best decision :)

Answer (score 1):

For Cassandra 4.0 the [documentation](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/4.0/getting_started/installing.html#prerequisites) mentions that the latest version of Java 8 (either OracleJDK or OpenJDK) must be installed:

> The latest version of Java 8, either the Oracle Java Standard Edition
>   8 or OpenJDK 8. To verify that you have the correct version of java
>   installed, type `java -version`.

Comment: Thanks, yeah no where there is mention of Java 10.